# understanding time: Is time simply the rate change?

Tags: relativity, time, big-bang

Is time simply the rate of change?

If this is the case and time was created during the big bang would it be the case that the closer you get to the start of the big bang the "slower" things change until you essentially approach a static, unchanging entity at the beginning of creation?

Also, to put this definition in relation to [Einstein's conclusions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time#Modern_physics) that "observers in motion relative to one another will measure different elapsed times for the same event." :
Wouldn't it be the case that saying the difference in elapsed time is the same as saying the difference in the rate of change.

With this definition there is no point in describing the "flow" of time or the "direction" of time because time doesn't move forward but rather things simply change according to the laws of physics.

Edit: Adding clarification based on @neil's comments:

The beginning of the big bang would be very busy, but if time was then created if you go back to the very beginning it seems there is no time and there is only a static environment.

So it seems to me that saying time has a direction makes no sense.  There is no direction in which time flows.  There is no time; unless time is defined as change.

So we have our three dimensional objects: and then we have those objects interact.  The interaction is what we experience as time.  Is this correct or is time more complicated than this?

Comment: If you're concerned with the rate at which things change, shouldn't things go *faster* as you approach the Big Bang? The first hour of the universe was an extremely busy time.

Comment: More generally and to the point: how do you determine "the rate of change" without a fixed standard for time, anyhow? Fast processes still happen now; just perhaps less frequently than before. That, and we're often more interested in glacially slow processes, such as human behaviour, and well, the movements of glaciers. It makes the most sense to establish a collection of commensurable standards of time reaching back to the Big Bang; but commensurability pretty much prevents any process of "time inflation" --- at least in how we *measure* time.

Comment: Things may happen "faster" compared to things happening on earth now but wouldn't you eventually reach the beginning where nothing is happening and you reach a static/stable environment

Comment: It depends on how you're trying to define a changing scale of time! If the "activity" (very vague) of the universe is getting slower with time in an exponential decay, then going backwards in time would look like watching a computer which performs one instruction in 1Gyr, a second instruction in .5Gyr, a third in .25Gyr, getting faster with time. If you "rescale time" so that each instruction takes one "operational time unit", what you find is not that things come to a rest but that you can squeeze in an infinite regress of activity immediately after the Big Bang. Very speculative of course!

Comment: I once read a science fiction suggestion of animate beings who have as time the change of a space direction with respect  to the others:dx/dz and dy/dz where z is "time", i.e. the beginning and ending of their "life"  an extent in two dimensional space.

Comment: I actually think the OP has intuitively stumbled on pre-symplectic spaces and the hamiltonian flows on them. A nice answer might also include how thermodynamics is capable of picking out the "correct" time direction, at least in cases of thermal equilibrium. This line of thinking has a prominent proponent in the form of Rovelli. (I might expand this comment into a proper answer later, though it will probably not be much use for the OP --- too formal --- but it might be interesting for other people.)

Comment: I admit how time apparently "flows" is a difficult problem and one of the most mysterious in physics. But reading one comment above I remember one of the famous quotes "Any intelligent fool can make things bigger and more complex... It takes a touch of genius - and a lot of courage to move in the opposite direction. "

Comment: @sb1 nicely said, lol

Comment: FWIW:  http://www.amazon.com/Time-Reborn-Crisis-Physics-Universe/dp/0544245598

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since for some reason this question has resurfaced, I would like to point to a [similar one posed later](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/23148/how-was-time-created/24262#24262) than this.

Observation of change is important to defining a concept of time. If there are no changes, no time can be defined. But it is also true that if space were not changing, no contours, we would not have a concept of space either. A total three dimensional uniformity would not register.

Our scientific time definition uses the concept of entropy to codify change in space, and entropy tells us that there exists an arrow of time.

In special relativity and general relativity time is defined as a fourth coordinate on par with the three space directions, with an extension to imaginary numbers for the mathematical transformations involved. The successful description of nature, particularly by special relativity, confirms the  use of time as a coordinate on par with the space coordinates.

It is the arrow of time that distinguishes it in behavior from the other coordinates as far as the theoretical description of nature goes.

Comment: it could be also added that entropy as an indicator of time is a relatively modern concept and not the only one. Surely the earliest thinkers compared cyclic processes with non-cyclic ones and found that some other non entropy-rising systems would behave as only one directional processes. I think of aging for example, compared to the tides or moon cycle.

Comment: What you're talking about is the subjective experience of time, not time itself.

Comment: How does this answer address what is time ? I think it circles around its direction.

Answer (score 2):

This question ("Is time simply the rate of change?") is too ambiguous to have any meaningful answer.  I can think of interpretations in which the question is vacuous (begging the question: "what is meant by 'rate of change'?"), tautological ("rate of change" == d/dt), or in which the answer is 'no' (GR).

You might find the answer you seek in this book:

- [*From Eternity to Here: The Quest for the Ultimate Theory of Time*](http://preposterousuniverse.com/eternitytohere/) by Sean Carroll.

Comment: to rephrase: is time a thing in itself or is time simply things changing? This is probably a hard question to articulate. Add that to my lack of understanding of physics :-)

Comment: @Jeremy: most questions that are hard to articulate in this way are not meaningful, they are only philosophical words that make the brain go in circles. The questions about time which are meaningful are those that can be answered by observations.

Comment: Would you recommend this book to a complete beginner?

Comment: @coder neither. Time is a term describing temporal motion. Asking if time exists is like asking if motion exists. Motion is not a thing, it's something that physical things do. Time is something that physical things do. Basically, we move through the spatial dimension and we time through the temporal dimension. Because the 2 dimensions are interlinked, the faster we move, the slower we time.

Answer (score 2):

Time is what is measured by clocks.

But how is time modelled in physical theories ?

In the Schrödinger equation time enters as an external parameter. How does this parameter correspond to the time measured by clocks ?

The following reference might be a good introduction to this and related questions concerning time and quantum mechanics : http://www.physedu.in/uploads/publication/1/7/28-1-3-The-challenging-concept-of-time-in-quantum-mechanics1401.pdf

Answer (score 2):

There's is no such notion as "time" in isolation from space. Since time is a measure of entropy of space, then time wouldn't exist if the space is absolutely static.

Imagine that one will somehow manage to 'rollback' the matter & energy to a state in which it was yesterday. Would this be a time travel? I don't see reasons why it wouldn't.

There are things not affected by time - say, physical laws and regularities. Since we assume that they are the innate property of the universe, we also assume that they exist out of the scope of time and space. That is, time didn't exist before the BigBang, but the laws did.

Edit: it's rather difficult for me, though, to imagine a physical law existing in isolation from things that it governs.

Comment: Physics Law is the description of the thing that it governs.

Answer (score 2):

I go with

> Time is the separation between distinct events that happen in the same place.

which is very general and not quantitative at all, but covers the basics. Given three distinct events that happen at the same place we can determine which happened between the other from just the values of the three separations. And it agrees with the notion that *"time is what a clock measures"*.

From the perspective of relativity this definition is the proper time.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly time is intriguing, but there are two different things going on here: (1) there is (classically) the manifold, (2) and the zeroth component of the momentum 4-vector.

To start, the temporal part of the gravitational potential does have some weird geometry that we aren't used to in everyday life and this certainly plays a role in some of the strangeness surrounding "time", but a decomposition of the EFE demonstrates that actually $g_{00}$ and $g_{0i}$ don't have time derivatives.  The temporal parts of the space-time manifold, are static, only the spatial parts, $g_{ij}$ are dynamic.  So where is this notion of "flow" coming from?

Instead, think of the manifold as a landscape, with something like a "temporal" direction.  Our movement through that direction, is determined by the zeroth component of the momentum 4-vector, energy, temporal momentum.  Why are almost all things in everyday life moving in the same "direction" of time? its not because we are all in the same river, its because we are all made of the same stuff.  If you want to relate "time" with a rate of change, a place to start looking is at the momentum 4-vector, not the spacetime manifold.

Answer (score 0):

A clear understanding of time in my opinion Still eludes us.

Within scope of classical Concepts there is a Perfectly valid practical definition of time. Which essentially is the correlations between the periodic behaviour of systems. For instance the behaviour of a pendulum is correlated with the behaviour of the motion of the sun around the planet as N number of periods pendulum corresponds to 1 Period of earth orbit around the sun. The property of periodicity in classical systems is essential in the definition of a clock.

The Question about arrow of time in my opinion Boils down to our inability to prepare system in precise initial conditions, Which only allows the possibility of predicting its behaviour on in a statistical Sense. We are also limited to measure only certain properties of a system, and we cannot acquire complete information. This is a limitation we must accept on our ability to perform experiments. In this sense, if we use the clock we defined only using Classical Concepts, then this implies that flows have a preferred direction ie, a the direction of incerasing entropy.

Question of time In my opinion will completely resolve Itself if one understands what a memory impression is. Memory being impression being permanent contains a record of the passing of time. I think it is very closely connected to the foundational Issues that plague Quantum measurement.

Saying this coming to your question on Time running Slower closer to the big-bang, In one sense One can say that there is no structure to measure the movement of time. But really to answer this question we have to wait for the discovery of Quantum Gravity.

Answer (score 0):

The 7 fundamental quantities are hard to define.

- Time
- Displacement/position
- Mass
- Temperature
- Current
- Amount of substance (e.i. the mole)
- Luminous intensity

More here: http://gravimotion.info/Physics_seven_basic_quantities.php

Time is just one of them. If someone asked me, I would say something like "Time is how long something lasts" or "Time is the duration of something". But that's circular; it's the same as saying "Time is how much time has passed". So it really doesn't say anything.

Any other physical quantity can be explained in terms of these 7 fundamental ones. E.i., velocity is how *far* something moves per *time unit*.

But how can you explain/define the fundamental ones themselves, then? My best answer is: **You can't**! You can only define it empirically or with examples. **Time is what a clock shows**, I heard someone say once.

You do though say that we can define *displacement* and *current*. But how? How would you do that without ending up in a similar looping circular explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Time is what makes the clock tick, not what it reads. Co-locating a clock with the event being timed insures they are both under the common influence of local time.

We might want to say that if time stopped the clock would also stop. Not so. The clock would cease to exist. Why is that? This is because if local time influences the clock, they both have to be of the same nature (no apples and oranges) in order to “operate” logically on each other. Therefore, the clock is also made of time, albeit, a more complex form of it. If time stopped, the clock would cease to exist!

A universe operational on logic (obeying the rule of non-contradiction, as it does) requires that it be all made of only one substance-process and be motivated in its evolution by a single type of cause. For that reason, the cause has to be built into the substance itself as a variable of the process; this is the rate of the process.

Time is the residual from space-time and is this spontaneous process and its rate of evolution is its main variable. The cause is a differential in the rate of time, the variable, as found in a gravity field. Gravity is a differential in the rate of time resulting in a differential in existence as a more probable position for existent inside the differential. This cause is everywhere and is the same in thermodynamics.

Gravity can be shown to be an entropic process. While an object falls in a gravity field, it moves spontaneously toward slower time rate. This slower time rate means longer seconds. In order to keep c constant (m/s)  longer seconds (s) require longer space (m), (cubed for volume). So, the object falling on earth is actually falling into larger space which is dispersion, the hallmark of entropy.
Under the constancy of the speed of light c, thermodynamic may be seen interchangeably as dispersion in space or in time (lower power i.e. energy not lost, just dispersed in time).

In essence, the same type of cause is behind, gravity, QM, thermodynamics ... and in emergent spheres i.e. what makes atom and galaxies to form, waves to roll on the ocean and clouds to move across the sky.

M.LeBel

Answer (score -1):

The concept of time is intimately related with the concept of causality. If we don't have the notion that something can cause some other thing then there is no objective meaning to the word "time". It's causality which enables us to decide and describe which event is past and which is present.

In relativity, as we know, space and time are intimately related to each other. What is just space to some observer may be a combination of space and time for another. It is therefore helpful to think of a $4$ dimensional space called spacetime whose points represent events. An event therefore needs $4$ independent numbers to be uniquely specified. Out of this $4$ numbers one is a little special. If you draw a light cone at any point in this space then all except one of the axes will be outside the light cone. This special axis is the direction of time and the numbers it represent is "time".

Comment: Thanks for not commenting on the reason for the down vote. That's a huge relief ;)

Comment: +1 because this definitely doesn't deserve a -1 :-).  You essentially rephrase my question in the first part.  I could have rephrased as asking, "is it the case that time is simply causality?"  If this is the case then it seems the notion of a "flow" of time only exists because we have a memory of the past events; when in fact there is no past, there is no future, there is only stuff which interacts.  So the words "time", "causality" and "interaction" are interchangeable leaving us with only stuff that changes.

Comment: Not my downvote, but the concept of time does not require a concept of causality, which is notoriously hard to pin down in the microrealm and probably doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I disagree with you Ron. First it is dangerous to say that causality doesn't make any sense in the micro realm. If it were so, then how can you ever trust QFT which is fully consistent with S.R. and which requires causality to hold strictly. Secondly, if two events are space like separated in the micro realm how do you decide which has taken place earlier? You can't, unless you seriously modify the existing theories or unless you are talking about some as yet unknown QG theory.

Comment: @RonMaimon: However, it is true that in the microscopic world there may be processes which may not have any intrinsic "arrow of time". But that's an altogether different issue, right?

Comment: @sb1: "Causality" in quantum field theory is a different concept than macroscopic "cause and effect". Cause and effect refer to things like "I pushed the block, so the block moved forward". You could also say "The block moved forward, so I pushed the block", and it is only the increase of entropy that separates the two. There is no entropy in the microworld.

Comment: @Ron: I am afraid you are just confusing the "arrow of time" with causality. I have already stated about the lack of any "arrow of time" in micro world. Ok enough. I don't want to argue more.

Comment: @sb1: I am not confusing anything--- the two are the same. The microscopic notion of causality in Quantum Field Theory does not bear any relationship to cause and effect as the words are understood in the macro-realm.

Answer (score -1):

Time is something we do. Everything in the universe, except for massless particles, time. The word time is a term describing temporal motion. We move through the spatial dimension and we time through the temporal dimension. The rate at which we time is called our temporal velocity and speed is calculated by dividing how far we move through space, by how far we time. Temporal distances are measured in seconds, minutes, hours, days, years, etc.

Because the spatial dimension and temporal dimension are interlinked, our spatial velocity is inversely proportional to our temporal velocity. So, the faster we move, the slower we time. Now, our temporal velocity determines the rate at which atomic, biological and mechanical processes occur. This means, the faster we move through space, the slower we age.

To be cont.

Answer (score -2):

well the way time should be conceived is the same way you should look at motion or any type of energy kinetic or potential, ergo it should be treated as such.  example, when a object falls from a table the time it takes to travel through the air co insists with the space around it ("space-time to be precise which the fine gent below me is proclaiming). So your question comes up which the answer would most likely be yes. but not to forget time is also a unit of measurement such as length width and depth and we use it as such. it simply being the rate of change is plausible under certain theoretical works in the past which many have been trying to prove fact in the present.

Answer (score -4):

you seem to think time started with the big bang, how long was the matter there before the big bang? we are still only talking about half an equation. two points are still needed to justify either of our perspectives