# What is the definition of time?

Tags: time, definition

I wanted to know the definition of [time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time) just like as we define displacement, current etc.

**Note:**There should be no mention of time period or time interval in the definition.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17056/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15371/2451 and links therein.