# Is it possible to measure the speed of Time?

Tags: time

Is it possible to somehow measure the rate at which time is passing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a device that could measure the speed of time?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41237/)

Comment: Also related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/52048/

Comment: No, people clearly just make things up when they talk about the duration of things.

Comment: Yes, I've measured it. and it passes at the rate of one year per year. You may say what about leap years? My answer to that is it's a hair splitting quibble. It all evens out in the long run, which is why we have leap years. We are time travellers moving into the future.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to somehow measure the rate at which time is passing?

Yes, it's called a watch.

No, that's not a joke. A watch measures the local speed of time. It does so by measuring a time-dependant delay of some sort, like the mechanical release of stress in a spring, or counting the number of oscillations of a vibrating crystal.

Right now my watch is telling me that it is going at one second per second. It is for you too. It is for everyone That's the whole point of [relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_relativity).