# Can time be thought of in terms of subatomic progression?

Tags: time, time-dilation

> "The second is the duration of 9192631770 periods of the radiation corresponding to the transition between the two hyperfine levels of the ground state of the caesium 133 atom."

This implies that subatomic processes are happening at a rate that only appears constant. If we move the atomic clock away from the earth (away from gravity), the rate at which subatomic processes take place changes.

Is this incorrect? And can this be extended to things such as the speed of an electron  around a nucleus?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/235511/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15371/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Are you asking if the iteration rate of macroscopic processes is constant with respect to local comoving atomic clocks?

Comment: @gs no I'm asking if the speed of an electron  around a nucleus is constant with respect to  local comoving atomic clocks.

Comment: Electrons don’t have classical trajectories. Their behavior around a nucleus is described by a wavefunction, not an orbit.